# Problem with crontab

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

My script which starts a process and writes the PID of that process to file. This works 
as it's supposed to when I execute it from shell:

```
process & echo $! > /home/xxx/PIDs/process.pid
```

But when I let cron do that, the process is executed but the PID file is missing.
This is weird to me. What could be wrong?

The cronjob is a simple `@reboot` trigger. I tried, as Jeff Schaller mentioned,

```
*/10 * * * * /home/xxx/bin/process & echo $! > /home/xxx/PIDs/process.pid
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Are you running the command on the command line with the same user whose crontab should execute the job?  Do the owner of the crontab get any error messages in their email from cron?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like the user your cron job runs as, does not have permission to write the PID-file to `/home/xxx/PIDs/`.

This could be the case if e.g. `/home` is mounted over NFS for example, or perhaps due to things like SELinux.

Try checking local e-mail. In most setup's cron sends error to the local root user by e-mail.

It may also be worth to try running the command as user account `xxx` by specifying this in the crontab, or login as user `xxx` and run `crontab -e` to edit the 'personal' crontab of user `xxx`.

Comment: On most systems, `cron` would send an email to the owner of the crontab.  If the owner is root, then there should be no permission problem.  Also, the user mentions that they are able to run the command on the command line.  You answer has merit if it mentions the fact that it's _the user that owns the crontab_ that has to have write permission in the destination directory (the cron daemon itself will not try to write anything).

Comment: I use sudo crontab -e for editing so it's roots cron. I think something is going on with the external hdd. when i reboot i get a unmount fail and system hangs until it fully reboots. that's only the case when a process writes to file when it reboots. I could swear normally it rebooted without this unmount failure.

Comment: @Kusalananda : point taken: cron daemon iself does not try to write to /home/... Edited my answer.

Comment: Not /home is directly mounted as NFS but a subfolder on exHDD is mounted under /home. And that is also the place where the scripts stored.
Even tried with users cron but same.
I reinstalled cron with purge but old crontab was still there after reinstall. Anyways I'll test now if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sry I said scripts are at subfolder on exHDD thats not correct, they are stored in /home/subfolder but doesn't matter anymore.
reinstalling cron does it. Can't figure out why...